# Гарантирует ли C++17 RVO и NRVO?

Tags: c++, c++17

Собственно, вот и весь вопрос. Нигде не смог найти ответа, но слышал об этом.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: RVO да, NRVO нет.

Comment: Я не уверен, но по-моему copy elision и RVO/NRVO это не совсем одно и то же...

Comment: @zcorvid Да, это не одно и то же, RVO / NRVO являются одним из случаев copy / move ellision.